# Android have access to user info after login in few activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

Hey what is the best practices to save and share data after login or register user in app. I have data in mysql database. I use asynctask to connect and get data from database and after login i get userId, username, name, surname and i go to main activity. After that I have few activities where I have to use user info e.g. i'd like to download extra data about user or something else but in all situations I have to have access to userId.

So I don't know which way to use to have access to user info in next activity e.g Shared Preferences or make user class as singleton or maybe there is other method to do this? I'd like to have access to the data when I go to the next activity and i back to the first so when I use onResume() and on onPause().

And second question is which method to connect and get or post data from/to database is the best: asynctask and HttpURLConnection or Volley or Retrofit ? Now i use asynctask and HttpURLConnection.

Comment: About second qn, I think `volley` is good for communicating with the server. It's a personal opinion. I have used `AsyncTask` and `HttpURLConnection` for the same and not `Retrofit`.

Comment: About first, To access data from all activities I have made a class with `Application` context. And for storing persistent data like storing userID until user logs out, I have used sharedpreference. Hey, but it all comes down to ur preference.

Comment: @2942 ok thx for your answer. Now I create a class SessionManager where I user SharedPreference and it works.